# disable "Ok Google" programmatically

Tags: android

I have an application that does continuous hotrword detection by itself.
the problem is when in  googlequicksearchbox settings->Voice->"Ok Google" detection the "From the Google app" or "From any screen" is checked then I cannot regain access to the mic as it is recording for the google hotword recognizer.

I have 2 possible paths:

1. when I catch the recording error I can launch the '"OK Google" detection' fragment and hope the user will disable the setting (by broadcasting com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.action.HOTWORD_DETECTION_SETTINGS intent)
2. finding out if googlequicksearchbox has a content provider I can access and set it programatically

any thoughts would be much appreciated

Comment: did you find the answer ?